# Access denied, pattern match SurveyBot at HEADER? What does this mean?

Tags: php, mod-security

in my error log files I read following over and over:

`[Thu Feb 03 03:14:32 2011] [error] [client 64.246.165.200] mod_security: Access denied with code 500. Pattern match "SurveyBot" at HEADER("USER-AGENT") [hostname "mywebsite.be"] [uri "/nl/home"]`

`[Thu Feb 03 03:18:12 2011] [error] [client 64.246.161.190] mod_security: Access denied with code 500. Pattern match "SurveyBot" at HEADER("USER-AGENT") [hostname "mywebsite.com"] [uri "/en/home"]`

on and on and on
What does this mean??
Should I be taking any actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like your web server's [`mod_security` module](http://www.modsecurity.org/) denied access to a client that had the string "SurveyBot" in its `USER_AGENT` header.

Looks like just a rule to block useless robots - nothing to worry about, everything worked out as it was supposed to.

**Edit**: The rule indeed seems to be in mod_security's [bad robots list](https://mod-security.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mod-security/crs/trunk/base_rules/modsecurity_35_bad_robots.data).

Comment: It's probably in the rules because it was considered a "rogue" crawler rather. Albeit I cannot find any mentions in the OWASP mailing lists.